# Remove @Override annotation java

Tags: java

I am having same method name and signature in both Service and implementation class and I am getting error `Remove @Override annotation` for add addPet

`PetApiService interface`

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.JavaJAXRSCXFCDIServerCodegen", date = "2023-01-18T09:57:54.080Z[GMT]")public interface PetApiService {
      public Response addPet(Pet body, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response addPet(Long id, String name, Category category, List<String> photoUrls, List<Tag> tags, String status, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response deletePet(Long petId, String apiKey, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response findPetsByStatus(String status, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response findPetsByTags(List<String> tags, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response getPetById(Long petId, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response updatePet(Pet body, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response updatePet(Long id, String name, Category category, List<String> photoUrls, List<Tag> tags, String status, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response updatePetWithForm(Long petId, String name, String status, SecurityContext securityContext);
      public Response uploadFile(Long petId, Object body, String additionalMetadata, SecurityContext securityContext);
}
```

`PetApiServiceImpl.class`

```
@RequestScoped
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.JavaJAXRSCXFCDIServerCodegen", date = "2023-01-18T09:57:54.080Z[GMT]")public class PetApiServiceImpl implements PetApiService {
      @Override
      public Response addPet(Pet body, SecurityContext securityContext) {
      // do some magic!
      return Response.ok().entity("magic!").build();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The error message is about the `getInventory` method, which is not present in the interface, so it can't be overridden.

Comment: the Override annotation indicates that it's either in an interface you implement, or in a super class. If it's not, it can't be an overrided method, and can't have that annotation

Comment: You are sure that the question is swing related? Please review the used tags

Comment: sorry I have uploaded wrong  image of error message its get pet method only